# CircleCI - regex filtering match within string

Tags: circleci

I'm trying to filter to make sure the branch has a jira ticket name in it. The ticket name can be anywhere in the branch name.

```
      - uploadToJira:
          requires:
            - testDebug
            - testRelease
          filters:
            branches:
              only: /.*(jira|JIRA)-\d+.*/
```

This should match names like `feature-JIRA-18889-test` or `bug-JIRA-2344` or `jira-1233`, but it does not seem to do so (though the same regex works in Java). What am I doing wrong?

Update: The regex `/^pull.*/` works, which tells me it's matching on the pull request name for the branch (which is what circleci uses when it checks the code out). This seems like a bug in circleci, since `pull/383` doesn't leave you with enough information to match on branch name; they'll all be the same.

Comment: I'm just [reading this part of the docs](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#using-contexts-and-filtering-in-your-workflows).

Comment: I wonder if this is somewhat related: _Additionally, if a job requires any other jobs (directly or indirectly), you must use regular expressions to specify tag filters for those jobs_.

Comment: I appreciate you are filtering on branches here and not tags, but I wonder if you have to add this filter to the two dependent jobs in the workflow?

Comment: [Cross posted here](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/branch-filtering-using-regex-jira-ticket-name/29980). Please always add links to duplicate questions to all other copies, so that helpers do not expend duplicate effort.

Comment: @halfer I don't know that adding the filters to the dependents makes a lot of sense. I want those jobs to run regardless of whether or not the filter matches. I only want `uploadToJira` to run on "jira" named branches.

Comment: Yeah, that is a fair use case. The other thing you could do is to drop the YAML-based filter and put in a Bash conditional based on the branch, I think it is `CIRCLECI_BRANCH`. That would go in the job somewhere, I guess.

Comment: (It would still run, but you could output your own skipped message, and of course the conditional would prevent whatever action being taken).

Comment: It's weird, `CIRCLECI_BRANCH` is also `pull/383`. It does not provide the real branch name - I have to fetch it using a similar script to this one: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/access-real-branch-name-for-pull-request-fork-build/907. Maybe this is a configuration problem on my end.

Comment: Hmm, that is rather odd. However, yes you can use the API of the Git host, or you can probably just use `git branch` in the app folder, and it should give you the real thing (it's a real Git repo, after all).

Comment: Nope, if I ssh in, `git branch`, definitely says `pull/383`, and does not show the actual branch name.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if that is something set up by the Git host, and is outside of Circle's control? Could you try a `git branch -r` in your SSH session to see if the branch names you recognise are there?

Comment: Welp, I've figured it out. If the PR comes from a fork, you don't get the branch name. If it does not come from a fork, you do get the branch name. What a bummer.

Comment: Is that a Circle thing, or a Git/Bitbucket thing?

Comment: No idea! I think it might be circle. I worked around it with your idea, checking the branch in the script itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not matching due to the PR coming from a forked repository. The branch matching only works if it is a PR from a non-forked repository.

@halfer's suggestion above to not filter and have the script itself determine if it should run is what we ended up going with.

Here's what it looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

TICKET_NUMBER_REGEX='(ourproject|OURPROJECT)-[0-9]+'

# if CIRCLE_PR_NUMBER is NOT set (meaning it is not a PR 
# from a forked repository), then CIRCLE_BRANCH will 
# contain the real branch name
if [ -z "${CIRCLE_PR_NUMBER}" ]; then
    REAL_BRANCH_NAME="${CIRCLE_BRANCH}"

# if CIRCLE_PR_NUMBER is set, then we need to use it 
# to fetch the real branch name
else
    REAL_BRANCH_NAME=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/"${CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME}"/"${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}"/pulls/"${CIRCLE_PR_NUMBER}"?access_token="${GITHUB_TOKEN}" | jq -r '.head.ref')
fi

TICKET_NUMBER="$(echo "${REAL_BRANCH_NAME}" | grep -Eo "${TICKET_NUMBER_REGEX}")"

# if the ticket number regex does not match, then it's not 
# a feature branch, and we shouldn't upload to JIRA.
if [ -z "${TICKET_NUMBER}" ]; then
    echo 'Not uploading JIRA APKS for non-feature branch.'

# if it is a feature branch, then use the script to upload the
# build to the correct ticket.
else
    ./scripts/jiraBuildUpload.py -s -t "$(echo "${REAL_BRANCH_NAME}" | grep -Eo "${TICKET_NUMBER_REGEX}")"
fi
```